# Power Series Real analysis

Tags: real-analysis, power-series

I feel as if this should boil down to some type of geometric series but for the common ratio I get $(r+k-1)\cdot\frac{t}{k}$ which I don't know how to show is less than one to use the geometric series. I also tried to start from the function and produce the power series but I didn't get super far with that either.

[image]

Comment: What problem did you have producing the power series?  It's just the Taylor series; you need the successive derivatives of $(1-x)^{-r}$  As for the ratio test, remember that $r$ is a constant, so $\frac{r+k-1}{k}\to\ ?$

Comment: How does the derivative relate, sorry I may be missing something. And as per creating the power series I got that value but if that is the common ratio don’t I have to show that the value of that term is less than one for it to converge which is not always true if r is big?

Comment: The formula for the $k$th term in the Taylor series of $f$ about $a$ is $\frac1{k!}f^{(k)}(a)(x-a)^k$, so all you have to do is compute the derivatives $f^{(k)}(0)$, which is easy in this case.  As for you second point, you have to take $t$ into account.  If $|t|<1$, then the ratio will be $<1$ in absolute value, for $r$ sufficiently large.

Comment: Could you work out what you mean I’m not entirely sure what you’re pointing at